# Versions to publish the app

Tags: android, apk

I am programming android app and I have one question about the publishing of the app on Play Store. is it possible to publish the app only for the devices who have 1Gb of RAM of more? or is it possible to publish one apk for the devices with more than 1Gb RAM and other to the devices with less than 1Gb of RAM?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ActivityManager.getMemoryClass()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29) and [ActivityManager.getLargeMemoryClass()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getLargeMemoryClass%28%29) to verify the approximated memory values and propt user that his/her device does not have enough memory or you can can uncheck devices you don't want in developer console.